# Error while running Digits webclient for node.js

Tags: node.js, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

Referring this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/digits-server-client 
I am trying to send verification code to personal cell number using node js. 
When the following code snippet is executed, It logs [ { code: 0 } ] 
Did i miss out something?

```
    var digitsClient = require('digits-server-client');

   var digits = new digitsClient({
      digitsConsumerKey: 'YlNgs6zwm4QLmrzJBwRK3FcR5',
      digitsHost: "https://www.fabric.io"
    });

   digits.sendVerificationCode({
    phoneNumber: 9820XXXXXX,
    countryCode: 'IN'
    }).then(function (registrationToken) {

    console.log(registrationToken);
     }).then(null, function (error) {
         console.log('logging error');
       console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`[ { code: 0 } ]` means invalid phone number.

Put a valid phone number without 'XXXXXX' symbols.